# Can I control which nodes are selectable in a WPF TreeView?

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a two-level hierarchy displayed in a WPF TreeView, but I only want the child nodes to be selectable - basically the top level nodes are for categorisation but shouldn't be selectable by themselves.

Can I achieve this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

Define styles for each type of items, like Bijington wrote. for non-selectable nodes set the Focusable-Property of the container (TreeViewItem for TreeViews) to false.

Answer (score 2):

To do so you would need to override the style for treeview. Ideally you will have two types of treeview items one for your top-level nodes (im assuming folders) and another simply for the children, then you should be able to define how each item type in the tree behaves.
So create a style for each item type, then for the folder node simply change the trigger for is selected to do nothing.

Comment: but how would you prevent the treeview from semantically selecting the top level node? hiding the fact that the category is selected with visual styles may not be enough

Answer (score 1):

You can make only the child nodes selectable by using a trigger in a style, assuming all child nodes have no child nodes, like so:

```
<TreeView Name="MyTreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="true">
                     <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                 </Trigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
     </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Setting Focusable to false on a father TreeViewItems also prevents them from being selected.

Answer (score 0):

I've written at attached property that will unselect a treeviewitem as soon as it's selected:

```
public class TreeViewItemHelper
{
    public static bool GetIsSelectable(TreeViewItem obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsSelectableProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsSelectable(TreeViewItem obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsSelectableProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSelectable", typeof(bool), typeof(TreeViewItemHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(true, IsSelectablePropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void IsSelectablePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        TreeViewItem i = (TreeViewItem) o;
        i.Selected -= OnSelected;
        if(!GetIsSelectable(i))
        {
            i.Selected += OnSelected;
        }
    }

    private static void OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(sender==args.Source)
        {
            TreeViewItem i = (TreeViewItem)sender;
            i.IsSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you still lose the old selection when you click on an unselectable item :(